# Enable selection sound in settings

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

How can I enable/Disable the selection sound in our phone default settings programmatically.(Like button click,layout click sound etc)guyyzz help...

Comment: If I'm right then, you are asking for achieving sound effects on button click? right?

Comment: Not adding sounds effects.There is option called Audible Selection in our default Settings apk right.I want to toggle that selection programmatically..Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

***To Disable Sound Effects*** [putInt()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#putInt%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29)

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SOUND_EFFECTS_ENABLED, 0); //To disable
```

***To Enable Sound Effects***

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SOUND_EFFECTS_ENABLED, 1); //To Enable
```

Comment: I have a Preference setting for sounds in my app.You are suggesting in layout right(anyway to get that in java code).I want to toggle the sounds effect gloablly in java code with respect to Preferences.Thanks